# Subdomain similar to $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; for redirect?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a form (built with gravity forms) that redirects through a custom php file.

If I put redirect to "/custom_redirect.php" the form sends me to "http://www.subdomain.mydomain.com/:/custom_redirect.php" which leads to a 404, because of the "/:" or ":/" however you want to look at it.

If I source it through "http://www.mydomain.com/custom_redirect.php" it would work fine. But I need to grab the URL they came from first so I can include it in

```
header( 'Location: .........')
```

If I grab

```
$x = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$y = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

they print

```
(x).... /custom_redirect-x.php?JOHN+DOE&title=FOO+BAR
(y).... www.mydomain.com
```

similar to $y, "$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];",

...is there a way to grab the SUBDOMAIN so i can end up with

```
(y).... www.SUBDOMAIN.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Can you post the form ? and you might want to look into the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and parsing that

Comment: The problem I have with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is that it's completely unreliable

Comment: even with `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` could potentially be `parse_url('')` because the `HTTP_REFERER` isn't always set. Older browsers don't use it, and user agent can change it (or even not provide it at all)

Comment: do a `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see if you can see the variable that you need in any of those values.

Comment: If you have access to the form, can you simply modify the form to pass the subdomain ? naturally you will need some dbl checking on your page to be sure that is correct, but it might be a solution

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a plugin that we have to use for this particular application, so I don't have "direct" control of the form :/. and I just did a var dump (thanks!) and the only one with the value I need was `["HTTP_REFERER"]` which Is just too unreliable for my needs :(

Comment: Is my experience that `HTTP_REFERER` is not 100% reliable, but 99.999%. How about a Javascript redirect if `referer` is not set you show a page that grabs it from the history and redirects ? or, even better, a javascript that modify the form when the page loads or before  submission ?

Comment: How about `var_dump($GLOBALS)` ? anything in there ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in combination with [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
 $info = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 echo $info['host'];
```

Comment: I added that string to see the result and got `(z)=www.mydomain.com`, without the subdomain of the previous url :/

Comment: `http://www.subdomain.mydomain.com/` has the form. it needs to redirect through `http://www.mydomain.com/custom_redirect.php`. Using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` only provides me with `www.mydomain.com`, sans-subdomain.